# How can I access nested data via an array with parsed json

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am creating a vuetify simple table that is going to display various data elements. The problem is, some of those elements are based on relationships and nested. Getting the top level data is fine, and if I pull the nested data as a standalone, it works fine as well.

However, what I want to do is utilize an array to avoid repetitive html code for the table. Is this possible at all?

Below is the code as constructed for the table itself.

**HTML:**

```
   <v-simple-table fixed-header height="300px">
        <template v-slot:default>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="text-left">
                Attribute
              </th>
              <th class="text-left">
                Value
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr 
            v-for="(serviceProperty, idx) in serviceProperties" 
            :key="idx">
              <th>{{ serviceProperty.label }}</th>
              <td>{{ service[serviceProperty.value] }}</td>
            </tr>            
          </tbody>
        </template>
      </v-simple-table>
```

**JS:**

```
export default {
  name: "Details",
  data() {
    return {
      loading: true,
      service: {},
      serviceProperties: [
        {
          label: 'Description',
          value: 'description'
        },
         {
          label: 'Location',
          value: 'organization.locations[1].streetAddress'
        },        
        {
          label: 'EIN',
          value: 'organization.EIN'
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  props: ["serviceId"],
  async created() {
    this.service = await Vue.$serviceService.findOne(this.serviceId);
    this.loading = false;
  },
};
```

Comment: Adding logic for this is more complex and harder to understand and maintain than simply writing 10 more lines of HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

This seems unnecessarily complicated.

Consider using computed, like this

```js
...
  computed: {
    mappedData() {
      return this.service.map(item => {
        Description: item.Description,
        Location: item.organization.locations[1].streetAddress,
        EIN: item.organization.EIN
      })
    }
  }
...
```

You can then access the data in the template with:

```html
...
<element v-for="item in mappedData">
  {{item.Description}}
  {{item.Location}}
  {{item.EIN}}
</element>
...
```